# Connecting to a Raspberry PI that is connected to a router that I don't control

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am connecting a raspberry PI to a router of a client that I don't access to. The PI receives a dynamic IP from the router.

I have a web-server that controls several PI's that are all connected to different routers.

I want to be able to ssh the PI from the web-server. Obviously I don't have it's IP address.

I thought of some how configuring the PI to automatically open a terminal to the web-server. Though with this solution I would have lots of open sessions with all my PI's (There will be more than 50 PI's).

I would be happy to hear solutions,

Thanks.

Comment: how about using one these sites http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/

Comment: I don't understand how it will help since I don't have access to the router or I misunderstood the use of these services.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [post](http://carbonstone.blogspot.com/2013/08/setting-up-truly-portable-raspberry-pi.html) that explains how to connect to Pi in any network. Pay particular attention to the section **IP Address lookup by Hostname**

http://carbonstone.blogspot.com/2013/08/setting-up-truly-portable-raspberry-pi.html

Basically you use the ping command to lookup the Pi by it's hostname. If you want to do it programatically, you can parse the ping response to extract the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem a couple of weeks ago. 
This is the solution I found best for myself and my use:

The Raspberry Pi Foundation has got a MAC address that begins with [B8:27:EB](http://hwaddress.com/?q=B827EB000000). These first three octets are called [Organizationally Unique Identifiers, or OUI for short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier) , as they are used for "identifying a vendor, manufacturer, or other organization".

If you have SSH access to the network the Raspberry is connected to, you can use
[nmap](https://www.linux.com/learn/beginners-guide-nmap)
to scan the network for devices, and [pipe](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php) it with [grep](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/) to search for the devices.

The following bash code would be:

`nmap -p 22 192.168.0.1/24 | grep -A1 -B4 B8:27:EB`

What this code does is using nmap to scan a network (192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255) only on port 22 (SSH). Thereafter it searches, using grep, for the OUI belonging to Raspberry (B8:27:EB). It also displays one line after (-A1) and four lines before (-B4) the line containing the MAC address, so that you can find the IP address belonging to this MAC.

As an added bonus, you can also see whether or not the SSH-port is open.

This is how my result would be with two RPI on the network:

```
[root@LINUXSERVER ~]# nmap -p 22 192.168.0.1/24 | grep -A1 -B4 B8:27:EB
Nmap scan report for mynetwork.com (192.168.0.20)
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:FE:04:B5 (Unknown)
--
Nmap scan report for mynetwork2.com (192.168.0.239)
Host is up (0.00071s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:BB:B8:D3 (Unknown)
```

I hope it works for you! Best of luck.